# Any reason a pageviewcontroller could not contain tableviewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

There is something that bothers me about this concept of having table view controllers in a [page view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW5).

Yet, the customer wants separate pages with a table view in each page. It even makes sense in this case. However, I have not come across this before and something bothers me about it.

By the way, each row of a table will take a person to a detail view controller where the data can be edited.

I think if gesture recognizers are used that allow page transitions to happen via tapping or flicking, that could get in the way of the table rows.

I am going to check it out. However, my time is limited and I will have to bail quickly if this does not work out.

Anyone see gotchas on this and I should come up with another approach now?  :)

**update:** Another approach could be a navigation controller containing tableview controllers.

Comment: The only conflict I see is if your table needs to support swipe-to-delete.

Comment: good point. No, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basic case, there is no reason a PageViewController cannot contain a TableViewController